# Is it irony? Can you read it as rudeness?

Tags: offensive-language, sentence-meaning

I'm not native English as you will notice ;) that's why my below question.

The sentence which i received from native English person:

> "With regards to the xyz issues, I am asking what problem you have now?"

i feel it's as not most kind as I can imagine. I feel it like an irony "you again, what now? go away :/".

Do native English person will understand it also this way? Maybe it's not 100% rude but it has something not pleasant in it, am I right or not? How you will call/name/describe it?

Thanks,
Milosz

Comment: Yes, I can hear the "what now?" exasperation there. Try: *With regards to the xyz issues, what have you identified as the current problem?*

Comment: Yes, thanks I think I know how to write it nicer :) that sentence was sent to me :)

Comment: Whether it is a "you again" situation would depend on how many times you've dealt with the writer before. There could be exasperation there. It sounds to me like they're asking you to clarify something you said previously.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this.  And I don't think if we had enough information it would be an ELL question, but an interpersonal skills question.

Comment: Adding "now" *could* make it seem impatient, but it doesn't *have* to. It could simply mean "what's the problem at the moment." This could be especially true if there were any talk of past problems. As usual, tone depends on context.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit rude or at least a bit brusque, or it might just be an attempt to be efficient. Without being able to hear the tone of voice, and without knowledge of the history here (there clearly is some) one cannot be at ll sure.

> I am asking what problem you have now?

could mean: "I have fixed the problem you said you had, but you seem unsatisfied, wha is the remaining issue?"

Or it could mean something like: "You indicated that there was a problem but I didn't clearly understand its nature, please explain."

Or it could mean "I have provided several fixes on the xyz issue, what is wrong **this** time?" and be rather irritated.

The speaker may be feeling irritated, frustrated, harassed, or annoyed. Or may just be asking a factual question with no negative emotion. The history of prior interactions with this person may give a clue. Any negative feeling may be aimed at the situation in general, or at the other party. Again one cannot tell from this excerpt.